# Stimulus Reflex Callbacks stopped working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, stimulusjs, stimulus-reflex

Since I made some updates on my production server and redeployed the application, some of the client-side callbacks and promises between Stimulus Reflex and StimulusJS controllers suddenly stopped working. In development, everything is working fine, in production, just the `before` callbacks are working.

So, for example, this is working:

```
beforeReflex (element, reflex) {
    console.log(element)
    console.log(reflex)
    console.log("before")
  }
```

while this (and others) are not:

```
afterReflex (element, reflex) {
    console.log("after")
  }
```

The reflexes itself are working in development AND production, just the callbacks are not in production. I have no errors in the logfile, I have no JS errors in the console, Redis is running and everything else seems to be working.

The serverside callbacks inside the reflex (`after_reflex :show_success, only: [:update]`) are working aswell.

I can confirm it's not browser related (tested on Chrome, Firefox and Edge).

Could it be an issue that it's a company server behind a firewall? But then the other stuff shouldn't work aswell.

Does anyone have **any** idea where this could suddenly come from?

I don't know where to search anymore.

Comment: There has been a lot of work going into the lifcycles evens lately. Could you try to run the Gem on master? To see if this PR helps https://github.com/hopsoft/stimulus_reflex/pull/317/

Comment: @RolandStuder I already tried that, I don't think it's a gem related issue as It worked before.